# Conda to poetry environment

Tags: python, conda, python-poetry

I have a conda environment that I would like to convert to a poetry environment.

What I have tried is to translate the `environment.yaml` of the conda environment into a `pyproject.toml` file that poetry can read. Here you have the steps:

1. Generate the yaml file

   `conda env export --from-history > environment.yaml`

   The `--from-history` flag includes only the packages that I explicitly asked for. Here it is how the file looks like after installing numpy.

   ```
   # environment.yaml

   name: C:\Users\EDOCIC\Screepts\My_projects\Tests\conda2poetry\condaenv
   channels:
     - defaults
   dependencies:
     - numpy
   ```
2. Manually create the `pyproject.toml` file out of `environment.yaml`. I added the numpy version, which I got from `conda env export`. Here it is the result:

   ```
   # pyproject.toml

   [tool.poetry]
   name = "conda2poetry"
   version = "0.1.0"
   description = ""
   authors = [""]

   [tool.poetry.dependencies]
   python = "~3.7"
   numpy = "^1.21.5"

   [tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

   [build-system]
   requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
   build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
   ```
3. Create the environment with `poetry init`, which will automatically read the toml file.

The process seems to work but it's quite manual and prone to mistakes.
**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not a better way. Conda is a generic package manager and does not discern Python versus non-Python packages, therefore this has to be done with manual curation.

Additionally, package names might also differ. For example `py-opencv`(conda-forge) vs `opencv-python` (PyPi).

### Tips

In addition to pulling down the `--from-history` YAML, it may also help to dump out a `pip list --format=freeze`. This could help with resolving any tricky packages that use different names in Conda versus PyPI.

If the environment uses any PyPI packages directly, this won't be seen from a `conda env export --from-history`. However, these will appear when using `conda list` (entries with channel **pypi**) or plain `conda env export`, which would have a `dependencies.pip:` section if there are any.

Comment: Additionally, names might also differ, e.g. `py-opencv` (conda-forge) vs `opencv-python` (PyPi)

Comment: Another one is `ca-certificates` (conda) vs `certifi` (pypi). Do you follow any best practices?

Comment: @FlyingTeller this is wiki, so feel free to edit. Can serve as a working guide for best practices.

Comment: @edd313 `certifi` is the same on Conda and PyPI. The Conda `ca-certificates` is a non-Python package that provides updated trustworthy certificates for Certificate Authorities.